# MYSQL "every row excluded, but only once" join

Tags: mysql, join

Imagine a dance party where we line up boys on one side and girls on the other. Each boy is placed into table A, once and only once. Likewise for the girls in table B.

We then want to match up the boys in A once and only once with a girl in B, and likewise the girls in B need to match with one and only one boy in A.

A would have an ID column as a primary key and a b_id that would hold the ID of the girl they were matched with, or NULL if not yet matched.

B would have the same for the girls.

Tables would look like this:

```
table A (boys)
---------
|id|b_id|
---------
| 1|NULL|
| 2|NULL|
| 3|NULL|
| 4|NULL|
| 5|NULL|
| 6|NULL|
---------


table B (girls)
---------
|id|a_id|
---------
| 1|NULL|
| 2|NULL|
| 3|NULL|
| 4|NULL|
| 5|NULL|
| 6|NULL|
---------
```

What type of query would match one and only one boy with one and only one girl that is not yet matched? Results would look something like this:

```
results
-------------------------
|a.id|a.b_id|b.id|b.a_id|
-------------------------
|   1| NULL |   1| NULL |
|   2| NULL |   2| NULL |
|   3| NULL |   3| NULL |
|   4| NULL |   4| NULL |
|   5| NULL |   5| NULL |
|   6| NULL |   6| NULL |
-------------------------
```

I can get these results by using a temp table with unique indexes, but I'm looking for a query to give me the results without a temp table as the real application of this query is going against millions of rows on both sides.

Comment: Are the two tables supposed to have same number of rows (always)?

Comment: let me just point out that this is a normalization nightnare.  you should have a third table with the relationships.

Comment: Regardless of the normalization issue, why aren't you people +1ing this question? Imagine how easy life would be if everyone put this much effort into their question!

Comment: @Randy Not really. No one said that the girl and boy are matched with each other. Just because a girl is matched with a boy does not mean the boy is matched with the same girl.

Comment: @ypercube - no. Girls can come and go, boys can come and go. When they leave they are deleted and their matching mate is set to NULL so they can now be paired up again.

Comment: @MichaelMior - The boys and girls mutually match eachother. Imagine a dance where everyone is not mutually matched.

Comment: Yes, I misread the problem statement. In which case, Randy is correct. You might want to rethink the schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT boyUnmatched.id  AS aid
     , NULL             AS b_id   --- you really don't need these two
     , girlUnmatched.id AS bid 
     , NULL             AS a_id   --- columns, do you?
FROM
    ( SELECT @rownuma := @rownuma+1 AS rank
           , id 
      FROM a
         , (SELECT @rownuma :=0) AS dummy
      WHERE b_id IS NULL
      ORDER BY id
    ) AS boyUnmatched
  JOIN
    ( SELECT @rownumb := @rownumb+1 AS rank
           , id 
      FROM b
         , (SELECT @rownumb :=0) AS dummy
      WHERE a_id IS NULL
      ORDER BY id
    ) AS girlUnmatched
  ON boyUnmatched.rank = girlUnmatched.rank
```

Comment: I really like both the content and the style of this answer.

Comment: This comes back with no results at all. Please note, you alias boys and girls but the table names are a and b. I removed the alias and ran your query on the below dataset and get no result. I'm posting the sql to create and populate the tables in the comments below (one comment won't hold it all).

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `a` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `b_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;
    INSERT INTO `a` (`id`, `b_id`) VALUES
    (1, NULL),
    (2, NULL),
    (3, NULL),
    (4, NULL),
    (5, NULL),
    (6, NULL),
    (7, NULL),
    (8, NULL),
    (9, NULL),
    (10, NULL),
    (11, NULL),
    (12, NULL);

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `b` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `a_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
    INSERT INTO `b` (`id`, `a_id`) VALUES
    (1, NULL),
    (2, NULL),
    (3, NULL),
    (4, NULL),
    (5, NULL),
    (6, NULL),
    (7, NULL);

Comment: @dev: My mistake, editing. There should be two `@rownum` variables, not one.